# YouTube video turns black after few seconds

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

I am trying to watch YouTube videos, but after a few seconds the video area turns black even though it keeps on playing. Any tips why?

I use latest Chrome on Windows 7, and a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Comment: OS? Browser? Flash/HTML5? Device?

Comment: If on a desktop browser, consider upgrading your video drivers and/or try disabling hardware acceleration in your browser settings.

Comment: Looks like a lot of people experiencing the same issue = I doubt the problem is on your side.
http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/357416/youtube_keep_going_black_randomly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chrome developer suggested that you could try using the canary version. Some have seen this issue fixed with this branch of chrome.

https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/canary.html

(I have had this issue as well until I switched back to using the canary release and it's been a few hours without any issues.)